PyQt5 Drag'n'Drop перетащить виджет
Я пишу программу StickerPanel на Python с использованием PyQt5, и хочу чтоб можно было мышкой перетащить QPushButton в другое окно (например Telegram) в виде файла WEBP. Т. е. отправить объект. (есть похожая тема, но там получение объекта)
Как это можно сделать?

А по простому нажатию ЛКМ на кнопку сделаю просмотр увеличенной картинки. ПКМ - копировать в буфер обмена

Я хотел сделать через QLabel, но это надо дополнительно изменять размер картинки, и получилось криво. Поэтому сделал кнопкой

MainPlay TG , пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать, с учетом того, что вы написали в комментариях.

У вас не настолько большой код — вы можете добавить его в вопрос (нажмите кнопку "Редактировать"). Если не работает конкретная функция — укажите только функцию

Вот только вопрос я написал с телефона. Вставить код будет немного проблемно, и импорты тоже. Импорты вообще в другом файле

Короче надо сделать так, чтоб пользователь мог мышкой взять файл из виджета и перетащить его в другое приложение

Откатите ваше сообщение — не стоит добавлять информацию, являющуюся ответом, в текст самого вопроса. Вместо этого оформите свой ответ и примите его, если он вам помог в решении вашей проблемы

Сам разобрался и сделал через QDrag
class StickerButton(QPushButton):
  def mouseMoveEvent(self,event:QMouseEvent):
    img:QImage=IMAGES["ID картинки из кеша"]
    drag=QDrag(self)
    mime=QMimeData()
    mime.setImageData(img)
    # pixmap=QPixmap() # Размер слишком большой, отключил это
    # pixmap.convertFromImage(img)
    drag.setMimeData(mime)
    # drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
    drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.CopyAction)

